# On pressing backspace no event is triggered in chrome for android, So How to find whether backspace key is pressed or not?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

On pressing backspace key no event(keyup,keydown and keypress) is triggered in chrome android(specifically in Samsung S5(stock browser)), All other keys when pressed triggered the input events(keyup,keydown) and the keycode was zero. You can check amazon.in search bar, in all other devices, browsers on pressing backspace the suggestions will be getting changed based on the remaining characters, but not in Samsung S5 stock browser. But somehow in the same situation in google it works properly. How in google they would have detected the backspace key press event?